# Почему TeleBot падает с ошибкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Вот сам код

`````
````python
import telebot

from telebot import apihelper

TOKEN = '836764194:AAHd4h                           Kv1HVvIl1g'

apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://171.255.192.118:8080'}

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как тебя зовут?')

bot.polling()  
````
`````

Пробовал с прокси и без него.
Вот зависимости 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка https://pastebin.com/Abmitumf

Comment: а что за ошибка?

Comment: Забыл добавить, теперь есть

Comment: Прокси точно рабочий?

Comment: Да, прокси рабочий